# TableView not getting index using alertview with textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

In my app. i want when user select any row it will show alert with textfield so user write in to text and show it detailtext label. I got text from alert text but i cant get index which row selected and when it display text.here is my code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tblView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if([arrProductData containsObject:[arrProduct objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])
    {
        [arrProductData removeObject:[arrProduct objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    } else
    {
        [arrProductData addObject:[arrProduct objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add Quantity"
                                                        message:@"Please enter quantity"
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];
        alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
        [alert show];
    }
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

**Alert Action Method**

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        arrQuantity = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [arrQuantity addObject:[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text];
        NSLog(@"%@", [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text);
        [self.tblView reloadData];
    }
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath] ;

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if (tableView == self.tblView)
    {
      cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrQuantity objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }

        if([arrProductData containsObject:[arrProduct objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])
        {
            [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
        }
        else
        {
            [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
        }
    }
}
```

I also using two table view.so when i click on OK app will be crashed i getting error array bounds.please help me

Comment: You can give Tag to alert when you did select the row

Answer (score 0):

You can add the instruction

```
[alert setTag:indexPath.row];
```

before `[alert show];`

And in `alertView`'s `clickedButtonAtIndex` method in if block `if (buttonIndex == 0)` you can print the index like just for verification like

```
NSLog(@"Index Path selected : %d", alertView.tag);
```

Comment: But when it reload tableview how can set data in detailtext labe. Coz my main array count is 15 so how its handle.

Comment: That depends how you are handling the data structure to display the data, you should add the product and reload the table in alertView's delegate method itself and when you are deleting any product you can reload the table in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method

Answer (score 0):

Set tag to alertView as the table's index.

```
alert.tag = indexPath.row;   //This will give you indexPath for clicked row.
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath] ;

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if (tableView == self.tblView)
    {
        NSDictionary *dict = [arrProduct objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSLog(@"");


        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"product_name"]];

        if (selectedIndex == indexPath.row)
        {
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrQuantity objectAtIndex:selectedIndex]];
        }

        if([arrProductData containsObject:[arrProduct objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])
        {
            [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
        }
        else
        {
            [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *arrQuantity;

in viewDidLoad:
    arrQuantity = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

```
[alert setTag:indexPath.row];

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSMutableDictionary *arrQuantity;
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
       NSString *text = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
       if (text.length > 0) {
           [arrQuantity setObject:text forKey:@(alertView.tag)];
           [self.tblView reloadData];
       }
   }
}
```

Modify cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if (tableView == self.tblView)
{
    NSString *text = arrQuantity[@(indexPath.row)];
    if (text.length) {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",arrQuantity[@(indexPath.row)]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your app still getting crashed? or what is the exact problem that you are facing?